# Exchange 2010: Installing Outlook onto the Server

Tags: exchange-2010

It is not possible to use the Import-Mailbox or Export-Mailbox cmdlets unless Outlook 2010 x64 is installed on the Exchange server against which you try to run the command.

Does anyone have Outlook installed on their Exchange box? Are you aware of any issues or problems this might present? Are there any other cmdlets that require Outlook, or any other compelling reasons to install it on your Exchange server?

I've searched for Microsoft documentation or recommendations but can't find any.

EDIT: I'm trying to export to and import from PST files, not to another target mailbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion would be to plan an upgrade to Exchange 2010 SP1 RU3.  The SP1 removes the requirement to have outlook installed on the servers to import / export mailboxes.

Although, I do have Outlook 2010 x64 installed while trying to resolve the export to .pst issue.  We have had no issues while it's been installed.  We are moving to SP1 in the next week or so.

Comment: When I saw I had to install outlook to do the same thing, I decided to go this path as well. Just keep in mind that the import syntax changes completely when using SP1. SP1 upgrade is simple enough thankfully.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the most sensible approach. Do you have a link to any documentation that covers this specific fix?

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely NO problem with installing Outlook on an Exchange 2007 or 2010 server. Exchange 2000/2003 had problems with this due to MAPI version conflicts. The newer versions of Exchange do not use MAPI for management, so you're safe. You should be aware, however, that there still exists a conflict with Outlook and BES on the same server because of BES' reliance on MAPI.

Exchange 2010 requires Outlook on the computer it is run from. It is recommended to install the Exchange Management tools on a different 64-bit computer with the 64-bit version of Outlook installed. It is still possible, however, to install Outlook on your mailbox server and run the proper cmdlets from there.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you are not supposed to install Outlook on the server. You are supposed to install the Exchange Management tools and other prerequisites on a client computer. Here is a great article that will walk you through it: http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/exporting-importing-mailboxes-exchange-server-2010.html

Comment: Thanks for responding. Actually our support team have the Exchange management tools installed (although mostly we use remote Powershell), it's our policy not to RDP into any servers unless absolutely necessary  and to use only remote management tools. However, as explained in the link you have provided, it is not possible to export to or import from .pst files unless Outlook is installed on the Exchange server against which you perform the operation (even remotely). Apologies for not mentioning PSTs in my original question, I've updated it now.